# How to omit non-adjacent ally from a close attack?

Tags: dnd-4e

I want to use Burning Spray while flanking, without hurting the ally I flank with. Warcaster Tactics (feat for Hobgoblins from Dragon 419) lets you omit an *adjacent* square from a close attack, but the flanker is obviously not adjacent.

Is there any such possibility? Epic Destinies are too far away, but I am interesed in any other option.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Taking advantage of diagonals is your best bet.

*Spell Mastery* would come online at epic tier, but a) that's too late for you and b) you're no wizard.

You can still get flanking on Medium or smaller targets you hit with Burning Spray, as long as you flank them diagonally:

```
- B B B
X B B B
- O B B
- - X -
```

where you are either X, the enemy is O, and B is the remaining squares of your Burning Spray.

Against Large or larger enemies you can also avoid friendly fire entirely, either on a partial diagonal:

```
- X B B B
- O O B B
- O O B B
- - X - -
```

with the same key, or on a direct flank where you aim the blast diagonally (consider what would happen if the X on the bottom was one square to the left) or to the side:

```
- B B B   
- B B B   
- O O B   
X O O X
```

You have another trick you can pull against Large creatures, which occupy a 10' cube. It's maddeningly not been formally stated where I can see (it may have died with the old 4E forums) but a burst definitely extends in all directions from the origin, including up and down, and there's no real reason for a blast to work differently.

If your DM's okay with ruling that way, you can also airburst to only hit the Large creature, in a manner best visualized by treating that last diagram there as a side view:

```
- B B B   ^
- B B B   u
- O O B   p
X O O X   |
```

Comment: Why do you see it as abusing?

Comment: @András - Wording was more judgmental than is fair, that's been updated. But the core of it is that flanking something on a diagonal lets you notch your close burst into a position where it only endangers the enemy, which isn't possible when you flank something straight on. Having a tactical situation that only happens on the diagonal feels more like taking advantage of the limits of the tactical abstraction than a strategy you were intended to use. That doesn't make it any less possible or useful to you, though.

Answer (score 4):

After a search, the only other method I have been able to find for omitting squares from a burst or blast attack is the Spell Accuracy feat (from the *Player's Handbook*, page 207) This feat requires the user be a 21st level wizard, and allows them to exclude squares from their close and area attacks equal to their Wisdom modifier. Not much use for a non-epic sorcerer, unfortunately.